# Is text grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Is this text grammatically correct? I am not sure about Past Simple and Present Perfect in one sentence. Thank you for help in advance.
In England there has been coming a lot of sad news regarding Corona Virus. The UK, which were in doubt of the danger of the Virus at first, have changed their methods against the virus. In the beginning, the schools, public places and all places with lots of people weren’t closed until the moment, the Prime Minister, the secretary of Health and one of his advisers have tested positive. After that moment the UK have joined the countries which have taken serious measures to contain the virus for example closing schools, public places, almost all other places where people come together except for groceries, in order to make the people stay at home.

Comment: Please just quote the single sentence, or make it obvious which sentence it is in your text. Also, **why** are you "not sure"? Please read "How do I ask about checking my text?" on our [Help page](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sry. It was my first question. I don't know if it is correct to use Past Simple and Present Perfect in a single sentence. Example: The UK, which was in doubt of the danger of the Virus at first, have changed their methods against the virus weren’t closed until the moment, the Prime Minister, the secretary of Health and one of his advisers have tested positive.

Comment: My first question after a long time.

Comment: To answer your question, “No. It’s not correct.”

Comment: @Jim I don't agree. The name of a country should take a singular verb, but _The UK, which was in doubt... has changed its methods_ is grammatically acceptable.

Comment: @KateBunting - I was referring to: "*In the beginning, the schools, public places and all places with lots of people weren’t closed until the moment, the Prime Minister, the secretary of Health and one of his advisers **have** tested positive.*"  It should just be  "*until the moment the PM, ... and one of his advisers **tested** positive.  After that momoent the UK **[decided to join]/[joined]***..."

Comment: @Jim OK, I agree with that. The statement is inaccurate, BTW. Lockdown in the UK started several days before the PM was found to have the virus.